# Monitor goes black after playing games

Tags: windows-10, display, desktop-computer, gaming

Lately, after I quit a game, it happens that the monitor goes black and goes basically in some kind of standby. It doesn't happen always (today it's just the second time that it happens), but I really don't understand what the problem could be. I cannot really tell even if it's just the monitor or the whole computer freezes, in fact, I've been forced to restart the pc using the button. Any help, please?

Comment: If this happens, can you press numlock to enable-disable the numlock light? or capslock or scroll lock? This will basically tell you if the pc crashed or not.

Comment: Ah, actually I haven't tried it. I really forgot to try this. What it could be if it is just the monitor that does it? And what if it is the whole pc?

Comment: Lets not get ahead of ourselves. We first need to find out if its the computer or just the monitor.

Comment: @LPChip the problem just happened and it's the pc that crashes, because I used your method and they don't light up

Comment: Okay, so you need to go to `start`>`control panel`>`administrative tools`>`Event log` and see what happens the moment it crashes. It should provide you with the necessary information. It is likely doing a BSoD but somehow your screen turns off, and the BSoD info will tell you why.